# Meaning of "to-be"

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can somebody please explain the meaning of "to-be" here:

> Yet we should not be disappointed at the sight of an empty seat, for the power of the sacred place still resonates and can be felt by anyone who stands in the presence of the spot where the Buddha-to-be sat and was sheltered by the sacred tree on the day of his awakening.

As I understand, it's about an event in the future but why then did the author use past simple after that?

Comment: Siddhartha sat there, in the past, and was not yet the Buddha. He was *at that time* the Buddha-to-be.

Comment: Cab you highlight the version of 'to be' in that passage? I can't figure out which one you're referring to.

Comment: I doubt the cited text was written by a native Anglophone (certainly not a *competent* one). You can't *stand in the presence of a **place*** (the ***spot, location*** where the Buddha-to-be sat).

Answer (score 2):

In this paragraph, "to-be" is denoting that the referenced individual was not the Buddha yet. For example, we can apply the same to a pregnant woman:

> The young mother-to-be wept with joy as she viewed the ultrasound of her unborn child.

Since a pregnant woman is not yet a mother, the use of "to-be" denotes that she is expecting or is expected to be a mother in the near future.